# How to use Inner Join and Left Outer Join together?

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I have two queries and I have to merge the second query into the 1st one such that it fetches the details of only those items that are currently present in the shelf( of all departments for that particular store Id).

Tables :

```
Item : item, uniqueLabel, ItemScale, ItemExpiry  // columns can have duplicates

Description : uniqueLabel, itemName //fields have unique value
Store :  StoreId, ShelfNo  // fields have unique values
Department : ShelfNo, ItemNo ( There can be duplicate items in a single Shelf)
```

I need to merge these two functionalities into one.

Query 1 to fetch details of items.

```
select item, Description.itemName, ItemScale, ItemExpiry 
from Item left outer join Description on (Item.uniqueLabel = Description.uniqueLabel)
where Item.uniqueLabel like '11%' //uniqueLabel starting from 11
order by Item.uniqueLabel
```

Query 2 to fetch details of all items that are in the Shelf(of all departments) for that store.

```
select itemNo from Store, Department
where Store.ShelfNo = Department.ShelfNo
and Department.itemNo is not null and Store.StoreId in('12345')
```

My Effort :

```
select itemNo, Description.itemName, ItemScale, ItemExpiry

from Item, Description, Department

where Department.itemNo = Item.item

Item.uniqueLabel = Description.uniqueLabel

where Item.uniqueLabel like '11%'
```

But this is fetching a lot amount of data.

Comment: You need to switch to explicit `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: Please provide sample data desired results, and an explanation of the logic you are using.  Also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from trying to use the out-dated comma operator for your inner joins.

If you switch to the "modern" (standardised in 1992) JOIN syntax for Query 2, it will look something like this:

```sql
SELECT itemNo
FROM Store
INNER JOIN Department 
   ON Store.ShelfNo = Department.ShelfNo
WHERE Department.itemNo is not null 
   AND Store.StoreId in('12345')
```

You can then add in Item as a second INNER JOIN, relating it to the Department:

```sql
SELECT itemNo
FROM Store
INNER JOIN Department 
   ON Store.ShelfNo = Department.ShelfNo
INNER JOIN Item
   ON Department.itemNo = Item.item
WHERE Department.itemNo is not null 
   AND Store.StoreId in('12345')
```

And then add in your LEFT OUTER JOIN and extra WHERE condition from Query 1:

```sql
SELECT itemNo, Description.itemName, ItemScale, ItemExpiry
FROM Store
INNER JOIN Department 
   ON Store.ShelfNo = Department.ShelfNo
INNER JOIN Item
   ON Department.itemNo = Item.item
LEFT OUTER JOIN Description 
   ON Item.uniqueLabel = Description.uniqueLabel
WHERE Department.itemNo is not null 
   AND Store.StoreId in('12345')
   AND Item.uniqueLabel like '11%'
```

That query may not be exactly what you want, and some of the conditions are possibly redundant once the queries are merged, but hopefully this shows how the explicit join syntax can mix INNER and OUTER joins.

Comment: Just a note, the WHERE clause's `Department.itemNo is not null` is redundant, since the same column already is used in join condition - so it can't be null.

Comment: @jarlh True; I was concentrating on the process of merging the queries, rather than looking at whether they actually make sense.